# Using DateTime.ParseExact On Aug 8, 2019 4:45:19 PM

Tags: string, vb.net, datetime, parsing

I am trying to use DateTime.ParseExact on the string of "Aug 8, 2019 4:45:19 PM". But every way that I have tried it, I am getting the error message of "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

I've already tried using DateTime.Parse but it is giving me an inaccurate time back.

It gives me:

```
08/08/2019 04:45:19
```

instead of:

```
08/08/2019 16:45:19
```

The code that I have so far is:

```
Import System.Globalization

Dim dateTimeExample As DateTime = Nothing
Dim format As String = "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
Dim provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
Dim text As String = "Aug 8, 2019 4:45:19 PM"

dateTimeExample = DateTime.ParseExact(text, format, provider)
```

The desired output I am looking for would be the DateTime of:

```
08-08-2019 16:45:19
```

Comment: To get that output format, are you specifying the hour as `hh` instead of `HH`?

Comment: @halfer Much appreciated, you were right! I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@madreflection provided the correct answer in the comments. I just had to change "hh" to "HH". I'm going to post the answer in C# but you will see what the issue was if you just look at the format of "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss".

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace DateTimeParse
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime dateTimeExample;
            String format = "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            String text = "Aug 8, 2019 4:45:19 PM";

            dateTimeExample = DateTime.ParseExact(text, format, provider);

            Console.WriteLine(dateTimeExample.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
08/08/2019 16:45:19
```